# I'm facing this error in client side in React,js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Join from './components/Join';
import Chat from './components/Chat';

const App = () => (
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Join} />
        <Route path='/chat' component={Chat} />
    </Routes>
);

export default App;
```

It thows error like "Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a  component."

Here is the ERROR:
[image]"

Comment: You aren't using `useRoutes` at all in the code you shared.

Comment: Can you please show me the code structure , Thank You.

Comment: You have imported `BrowserRouter` but not using it. Kinda sus, huh? You need to wrap your entire app content into it `<BrowserRouter><Routes>....`

Comment: It looks like you're using v6 of react router. The `<Route>` syntax [should be](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v6): `<Route path='/chat' element={<Chat />} />`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your app in the BrowserRouter component in order to be able to use routing

So the code in index.js will be as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter> <App /> </BrowserRouter>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

You could instead wrap the app in App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Join from './components/Join';
import Chat from './components/Chat';

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Join} />
        <Route path='/chat' component={Chat} />
    </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
    export default App;
```

but for cleaner code, do the first approach

Comment: Failed to compile
./src/index.js
  Line 6:  'BrowserRouter' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Comment: Import BrowserRouter first before using it from react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code inside `<BrowserRouter>` making sure it isn’t in the app itself but higher up in the tree.

Comment: It shows error like this "Failed to compile
./src/index.js
  Line 6:  'BrowserRouter' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).